# Contact form 7 custom labels

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm trying to integrate contact form 7 with my custom labels. I'm doing something like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="1">Yes, i do.</label>
  [checkbox c-checkbox-1 id:1 ]
</div>
```

Checkboxes don't even render and i tried various combinations. Any ideas on why does it behave like this?

Comment: can you put rendered output to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Yes, i do. 
[checkbox c-checkbox-1 id:1 ]</label>
</div>
```